# Javascript File Contents

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

So I got this script that is supposed to output the file contents of an uploaded file in base64 encoding, the problem is that it also outputs something like data:image/jpeg;base64, at the beginning of the encoded output. What do I need to do so this script just outputs the encoded file contents of the uploaded file and not data:image/jpeg;base64, etc?

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var sizef = document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0].size;
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            document.getElementById("uploadImageValue").value = oFREvent.target.result; 
        };
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#viewSource').click(function ()
        {
            var imgUrl = $('#uploadImageValue').val();
            document.write(imgUrl);

        });
    });
    </script>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="uploadImageValue" name="uploadImageValue" value="" />
        <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><br />
        <input id="uploadImage" style="width:120px" type="file" size="10" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="viewSource">Source file</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code to

```
document.write(imgUrl.split(',').pop());
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
var imgUrl = $('#uploadImageValue').val().split(',').pop();                     
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```